# How can I get the Design mode of a table without going through "Object explorer"?

Tags: sql, database, ssms, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to use SQL Server Management Studio to edit database tables. But I can't seem to access the databases themselves through "Object explorer" ([SQL Server Management Studio 2012 hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970989/sql-server-management-studio-2012-hangs)).

How can I get the Design mode of a table without going through that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command line:

For instance, if your username is bobby and your password is foo, use:

```
C:> sqlcmd -U bobby -P foo
```

Then select your database with `use whatever_your_db_name_is`  # Note you **do** literally type `use`

then describe [table_name]

To list all tables:  `sp_help` works and you can also use
`select * from SYSOBJECTS where TYPE = 'U' order by NAME`
which you can obviously change to meet your needs.

Comment: I tried that but got "sqlcmd: 'use ... ' Unexpected argument. (and by the way – it's a remote server I'm connecting to.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's not possible to open from TSQL any new tab in design mode for a table or view, the only way to do it is through the object explorer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/open-the-query-and-view-designer-visual-database-tools