# MSSQL 2014 management studio delay notification

Tags: sql-server

Studio management 2014

This is becoming insanely frustrating and completely random. We cannot work anymore on the SQL because any small action we do will lock SSMS and will force us to end task.

In the middle of the work a popup appears: "SSMS is waiting for an operation to complete. bla bla bla" with two options: SWITCH TO and CONTINUE WAITING.

None of them does anything, not clear which operation is it talking about.

This happens when trying to open a table, a view or even pasting into a query window. When typing the query manually it doesn't happen!
Ending task and reopening the SMSS will immediately result in the same.

We tried to:

1. Restart SQL server
2. Right clicking in the taskbar (Someone suggested that)
3. Using SSMS from another network computer
4. Running select * from sys.sysprocesses where blocked<>0. there were no results.

Because of point 3 we assume that the problem is not in the SSMS, but in the SQL instance?

Last time it was resolved by itself, the next time I connected after a day. 
Please help, we wasted hours here.

Thanks

Comment: Is this issue _only_ happening when you connect to a particular SQL instance?  Is it happening when you run SSMS from another mchine and connect to that same instance?

Comment: Try disabling AutoRecover (Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover) and see if it makes any difference. I had similar issues in Visual Studio that were solved after disabling AutoRecover.

Comment: I'm sure this is driving you crazy.  The first step is to narrow done the fault.  You need to know if it is the SQL Server, a poorly performing network, an underpowered laptop, an overzealous firewall or something else.  Have you reviewed the SQL Server logs?  Have you reviewed the Windows logs on the local machine?

Comment: Dan Field, yes, that's what I checked in point 3.

Comment: It's not related to performance. The software and other reports can work at the same time without any problem. it's a bug in the SSMS/SQL related to some lock out.

Comment: Also, check if you have any AddIns enabled. For a quick reference navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Shell (should be same for you) and see if you have an AddIns key there. If there are any, try disabling them. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have backups running throughout the day?

Comment: Maybe this could help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970989/sql-server-management-studio-2012-hangs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that ending task of RDPclip on the remote computer solved the issue.

I will see when this happens again if doing it resolving it.